# Rails 3 - Referencing a CSS class to form elements in an Object Dot Style

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3

Can someone please show me the syntax for adding a CSS class to the two form elements of the "f" form object below?

A link to the specific documentation is OK, too. I found stuff for select_box but nothing for the form elements shown below.

```
 ## A view...
 <div id="email_label">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<%= f.label :password, :class => "myCSSclass" %>
```

You could do something like the above. hope it helps.

And place the CSS file in the `app/assets/stylesheets/<cssFileName.css>`